# Zend GData - Share sheet

Tags: zend-framework, google-docs, gdata, google-drive-api, zend-gdata

I would like to share a Google Docs (spread)sheet via Zend GData API (in PHP).

Is there a way to do it via API?

Alternatively, I could create the sheet in a collection, which is already shared. But could not find a way to do it either.

Best,
David

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can share a file using the new Google Drive API: https://developers.google.com/drive/manage-sharing

It doesn't use the Zend library but the documentation includes PHP snippets for all methods and a complete sample application in the same programming language:

https://developers.google.com/drive/examples/php